# print array of object in javascript and print in html tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-maps, for-loop

i am using storelocater.js for multiple location in google map and show the information according to the location with image. i can show only one image but i want to show multiple images inside the information panel. link this

[image: Image how I want to show]

Here is my code

```
    var panelDiv = document.getElementById('panel');
storeLocator.Panel.NO_STORES_IN_VIEW_HTML_ = '<li class="no-stores">The nearest outlet:</li>';
  var Store = storeLocator.Store;
  Store.prototype.generateFieldsHTML_ = function(fields) {
    var html = '';
    html += '<div class="store-data">';
    if(this.props_['title']){
      html += '<div class="title"><div class="img-list clearfix">' + 
      for (var i = 0; i <= this.props_[images].length; i++) {
        console.log(this.props_[images[i]]);
        // <img src=' + this.props_['images'] + '>
      }
  + '</div></div>'
    }
    html += '</div>';
    return html;
  }
  var data = new storeLocator.StaticDataFeed;
  data.setStores([
    new storeLocator.Store('store02', new google.maps.LatLng(27.67663,85.31093), null, {images: ["img/thapathalil.jpg","img/thapathalil.jpg","img/thapathalil.jpg"]})
  ]);
```

and it shows:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for...

how can i solve this?? how can i fetch location inside of "images"

THANKS in advance

Comment: can you please add the issue/error you are facing? or may be how is it rendering ?

Comment: i've edited my code. please check out.

Comment: @NiranjanShakya did you checked [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46663141/3669624) below?!

Comment: @chsdk yes and thanks it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for...` because you used the `for..loop` in the string concatenation statement, directly after the `+` sign.

Change this code :

```
html += '<div class="title"><div class="img-list clearfix">' + 
for (var i = 0; i <= this.props_[images].length; i++) {
  console.log(this.props_[images[i]]);
  // <img src=' + this.props_['images'] + '>
}
+ '</div></div>'
```

To the following:

```
html += '<div class="title"><div class="img-list clearfix">';
for (var i = 0; i <= this.props_['images'].length; i++) {
  console.log(this.props_['images'][i]);
  html += '<img src=' + this.props_['images'][i] + '>';
}
html += '</div></div>'
```

**Note:**

- You should separate the concatenation of strings to the `html`
  variable and the `for` loop logic, using `html +=` instead of just using concatenation with `+` sign on multiple lines.
- Make sure to wrap the properties names between two `''` while accessing your objects, like in `this.props_[images]` where it should be `this.props_['images']` and in `this.props_[images[i]]` where it should be `this.props_['images'][i]`.
- And the first 2 lines of your `html` variable decalaration and the concatenation, `var html = ''; html += '<div class="store-data">';` can be shortened to just `var html = '<div class="store-data">';`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo. Change this:

```
console.log(this.props_[images[i]])
```

to

```
console.log(this.props_['images'][i])
```

And you should use

```
i < this.props_['images'].length
```

So try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.props_['images'].length; i++) {
    console.log(this.props_['images'][i]);
}
```

Comment: The interesting part is the full error message. Please add this to your question, please.